# How to search through a dataframe and print the results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv "employees.csv" that I am turning into a new DataFrame "Employees Filtered". The objective is to find all employees whose `last_name` starts with the letter "S" and print the results.

```
employee_id first_name     last_name       email    department_id   favorite_food   birthday
1   1   Richard         Sanchez       rsanchez@yahoo.com 1     Cheese       9/20/1965
2   2   Jon Snow    jsnow@yahoo.com                  1     Cheese   9/20/1988
3   3   Michael Scott   mscott@yahoo.com           3       Sinigang 9/20/2001
4   4   Leslie  Knope   lknope.yahoo.com@gmail.com  2      UNKNOWN  9/20/2014
```

This is the code I am using and these are the results printing.

```py
employees_4_1 = pd.DataFrame([employees_merged['last_name'].str.startswith('S')])

print(employees_4_1)
```

Results:

```py
last_name  True  True  True  False
```

I am not looking for the `True True False`. Rather, I am looking to print the names of the `last_name` starting with the letter "S".

Answer (score 2):

what you have created is boolean mask. Combine this mask with `.loc`:

```py
mask = employees_merged["last_name"].str.startswith("S")

print(employees_merged.loc[mask, ["first_name", "last_name"]])
```

Prints:

```
  first_name last_name
1    Richard   Sanchez
2        Jon      Snow
3    Michael     Scott
```

---

If you want all columns:

```py
print(employees_merged[mask])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in one step by directly filtering the employees DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'employee_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'first_name': ['Richard', 'Jon', 'Michael', 'Leslie'],
    'last_name': ['Sanchez', 'Snow', 'Scott', 'Knope'],
    'email': ['rsanchez@yahoo.com', 'jsnow@yahoo.com', 'mscott@yahoo.com', 'lknope.yahoo.com@gmail.com'],
    'department_id': [1, 1, 3, 2],
    'favorite_food': ['Cheese', 'Cheese', 'Sinigang', 'UNKNOWN'],
    'birthday': ['9/20/1965', '9/20/1988', '9/20/2001', '9/20/2014']
}

employees = pd.DataFrame(data)
employees_filtered = employees[employees['last_name'].str.startswith('S')]

print(employees_filtered)
```